# How to access listview items generated by ArrayAdapter by CLICKING ON BUTTON

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a ListView with ArrayAdapter. There is a Button along with TextView in the listview.xml. I want to retrieve data from that TextView by Clicking over corresponding buttons. 
My listview.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/btConfirmfriend"
    android:text="Confirm Friend"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My PendingRequest Class is as follows:

```
public class PendingRequest extends AddFriend {
TextView tvPending;
Button btConfirmfriend;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pendingrequest);
    final String[] s= getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("pending");
    System.out.println(s[1]);
    final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview,R.id.label,s);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    final View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
    btConfirmfriend = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirmfriend);
          btConfirmfriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection();
          //here I want to retrieve the value from List
            //System.out.println(s[adapter.]);
            int status = sc.confirmRequest(s[listView.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(PendingRequest.this);
            if (status == 1) {
                alert.setMessage("Friend has been Added");
                alert.show();
            } else {
                alert.setMessage("Sorry for inconvinient!!Try Again");
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

My pendingrequest.xml file is:-

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#e9abab"
    android:id="@+id/btSend"
    android:text="Pending Requests"
    />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

On clicking over the button nothing happening.onClick() method is not executing.Please help.

Comment: you just inflate the inflatedView and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a click listener on a view inside your list item, you need to write your own adapter for that -

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] list) {
            super(context, 0, list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            String item = getItem(position);
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
            // Lookup view for data population
            TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            Button btConfirmfriend = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirmfriend);

            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
            label.setText(item);

            btConfirmfriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getItem(position); //Get your selected text
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

And this is how you will set the adapter -

```
   final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,s);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct: `TextView btConfirmfriend = (Button) convertView...`? Why are you assigning a `Button` to a `TextView`?

Comment: Apparently a copy-paste mistake apparently, fixed that anyways.